# Python Regular Expression for validate numbers

Tags: python, regex

I want to create a regular expression for python snippet.

```
import re
pattern = "\d*\.?\d+[Ee]?[+-]?\d*"
r = re.compile(pattern)
txt = """
12
.12
12.5
12.5E4
12.5e4
12.4E+4
12E4
12e-4
"""
x = r.findall(txt)
print(x)
```

for filtering all valid input from txt this code is fine
but invalid input such as

> .12e, 12.3+4

are also allowed how can I fix this?

Comment: Smile :: Is not `123.` a valid format as well ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your regex to the following:

```
\d*\.?\d+(?:[Ee][+-]?\d+)?
```

This makes it so that if the `e` or `E` is there, there is always at least one digit, and so that `+` and `-` are only valid if they follow the `e` or `E`.

Note that you should be using a raw string literal to make sure the backslashes are escaped properly (doesn't affect this string in particular, but if you tried to use something like `\b` in your regex you would see the difference):

```
pattern = r"\d*\.?\d+(?:[Ee][+-]?\d+)?"
```

Comment: @downvoter You should comment on the answers you downvote and explain why you thought they were "not useful".

Answer (score 1):

The traditional regexp is along these lines:

```
pattern = (
    "(?:"
    r"\d+(?:\.\d+)(:?[Ee][-+]?\d+)"
    "|"
    r"\.\d+(:?[Ee][+-]?\d+)"
    ")"
)
```

But you can always do things the easy way:

```
def is_number(x):
    try:
        float(x)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False
```

Comment: Upvoted for the easy way. But I'd put `return True` in an `else` block.

Comment: Scary indeed. Try/catch shouldn't be an integral part of your code, IMO.

Comment: @adamdunson That sentiment is directly contrary to a general python [coding style](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html) -- EAFP: It's easier to ask for forgiveness than ask permission. Quote: *"This clean and fast style is characterized by the presence of many try and except statement"*.

Comment: @lazyr Good to know. In case it wasn't obvious, I'm fairly new to python, and I guess I've still got a lot of C-like habits.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use regex pattern

```
^(?=\.?\d)\d*(?:\.\d*)?(?:[eE][+-]?\d+)?$
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use regular expressions when you don't need to. It's more Pythonic[tm] (and easier, and more reliable) to let Python determine which ones are valid.

```
results = []
for line in txt.split():
    try:
        float(line)
    except ValueError:
        pass
    else:
        results.append(line)
print results
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try: `\d*\.?\d+(?:[Ee][+-]?\d+)?$`. This marks the exponent part as a group. I also added a `$` to make sure it matches the end of the string.

Also, since your regex contains `\`, you should use a raw string literal, example: `r'\n'`, which is literal `\n`, not the new line character.

The easier way would be to use `float()` and check for `ValueError` exception.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it (untested):

```
"\d*\.?\d+(?:[Ee][+-]\d)?\d*"
```

Comment: This uses a captured group, which you don't need.

Comment: Added the ?: just for you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here you are, probably the simplest yet:

```
^(\d*\.?\d+([Ee][+-]?\d+)?)$
```

Replace the ^ and $ with whatever you want the delims to be, whitespace or whatnot.

Solution explained:

Your solution

```
\d*\.?\d+[Ee]?[+-]?\d*
```

allowed for E's to be placed without digits -> hence the \d+ at the end of mine.
I also made the E's and optional +/-, followed by that manditory digit in a single group (i.e., enclosed it all in parenthesis) so they can't exist without each other. That entire group ([Ee][+-]?\d+) is optional (?) to accomodate for your number examples without that notaion.

Answer (score 0):

Or, avoiding regexes all together, use the Python tokenizer to find them:

**test2.txt**

> some bumph
>   2.34
>   1.7e2
>   some more bumph

**sample code**

```
from tokenize import generate_tokens, NUMBER

source = open('test2.txt').readline
numbers = [ (val, eval(val)) for typ, val, _, _, _ in generate_tokens(source) if typ==NUMBER]
print numbers
# [('2.34', 2.34), ('1.7e2', 170.0)]
```